# Getting a hardware profile from Fedora 12 after installation

Tags: computer-building, fedora, fedora-12

I've installed Fedora 12 on a computer I found in the trash (Bulk garbage day!) and I'm trying to figure out what's under the hood (seems like a stock dell but I'd like to know the details). Is there a way to get a hardware profile on Fedora after it's already installed on the harddrive? I saw an option at install but I skipped over it.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to use `smoltSendProfile -p` to get it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me here. You can pass `-n` instead and go to the [Smolt website](http://smolts.org/) and put the UUID into the text box to view it.

Answer (score 0):

You should (assuming that the command's the same) be able to just run lspci which should give you all of the information you need.

Comment: Smolt gives much more comprehensive results. http://smolts.org/client/show_all/pub_a9e5719d-c49a-4856-8b13-97b2cd15e0b8

Comment: true. because he's running fedora it's a better option. I'll up-vote your answer.